# Is it possible to deploy a JAX-RS web service to MobileFirst Server?

Tags: jax-rs, ibm-mobilefirst, websphere-liberty, mobilefirst-adapters

My team is working on the migration of a hybrid app from Tibco Silver Mobile(TSM) platform to IBM MobileFirst Platform.

I have a JAX-RS webservice developed using Weblogic IDE which is currently hosted on TSM server. This webservice does a security check for all the incoming back-end requests and pass the request to the back-end if it is from a valid source.

When the app will be migrated from TSM to MobileFirst platform the TSM server will be moved out of the scene. I am looking for some alternate options for hosting this JAX-RS webservice. I don't want to make any changes to the webservice since it is a tested and proven code used in the TSM based solution.

I understand from the IBM MobileFirst Platform 7.0 documentation that JAX-RS support is now available on the MobileFirst Server and JAX-RS specification based Java adapters can be developed and deployed to the server.

Can I deploy the above mentioned webservice .WAR file as such to MobileFirst Server, without making any customizations?

If yes, what is the procedure for deploying the webservice (.WAR) to MobileFirst Server?
If no, what are the alternate options that can be considered?

Comment: I don't believe anyone has yet done this so a confirmation would be difficult to provide. The JAX-RS based Java adapters in MFP 7.0 are packaged and deployed to the server, whereas you're talking about a .war file webapp that sits next to MFP in the application server (you deploy your .war file to WAS/Liberty/Tomcat - not to MFP Server). My guess is that things Should work, but I do suggest that you will try yourself and see how it goes. Deploying a .war file, in the development environment at least, means to just place it next to the other .war files in the filesystems and restarting Eclipse.

Comment: If you meant to deploy your JAX-RS service as is to the same Liberty profile server where MFP is deployed, there should be no problem. Liberty Profile supports JAX-RS 1.1 spec, so if your application is compliant with this spec then it should work. Consider the usage of Java adapter if you'd like to easily protect your JAX-RS service with MFP security or use MFP server api from inside your service. Transforming to Java adapter will require some effort (it is not just taking the WAR you have) but it may worth it (depends on your needs)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As indicated in the comments above:

MFP Server is actually a Java EE application deployed to a supported Java EE application server, WebSphere Liberty or full WebSphere ND being the normal options, though TomCat is also supported.

In principle your own JAX/RS WAR file can be deployed to these same servers, the details will depend upon exactly what Java EE features you exploit and you will need to understand those Java EE servers' administration model. MFP itself is not affected by this, and you need no MFP knowledge to do it. You just need to understand the chosen Java EE server. Personally I would start with WebSphere Liberty.

A further question would be whether it is better to isolate your JAX/RS and Mobile First servers into their own Java EE server instances. It can be easier to manage and scale if you keep things separate, but technically there should be no interference if you do co-locate them. It is pretty trivial to spin up a dedicated Liberty server.

A more interesting question is whether there is value in actually exploiting the MFP Adapter capability to create JAX/RS services. In effect it's your familiar JAX/RS programming model but packaged slightly differently, deployed as a MFP adapter, and with the option explicitly to exploit the MFP security model and easily call other MFP adapters.

Personally, if I were coming to a project with no existing JAX/RS services and have commited to MFP and its security model then I would do my JAX/RS in the MFP Adapters.